# Vue 3 Pinia state not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

My pinia store looks like this:

```
import {
    defineStore
} from 'pinia'

export const useMessageActionsStore = defineStore({
    id: 'messageActions',
    state: () => ({
        reply: [],
        message_sent: false,
        hiddenVaultSetup: false,

    }),

 actions: { 

            async hideMessage(messageId) {
            await axios
                .post(`/api/message/${messageId}/hide`)
                .then((response) => {})
                .catch((error) => {
                    // console.log(error);
                    // console.log(error.response.status);
                    // if (error.response.status == 403) {
                    console.log('hiddenValueSetup:', this.hiddenVaultSetup);
                    this.hiddenVaultSetup = true;
                    console.log('hiddenValueSetup:', this.hiddenVaultSetup);
                    // }
                })
        }    }
})
```

When the first log runs it returns: `hiddenValueSetup: false` and when the second runs after the line `this.hiddenVaultSetup = true;` it returns `hiddenValueSetup: true` but somehow, the state `hiddenValueSetup` remains false, even in the vue devtools. What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: " the state hiddenValueSetup remains false, even in the vue devtools" - how did you check that? That you see it this way in devtools means that the problem is specific to devtools

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce, see [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/github/piniajs/example-vue-3-vite?file=src%2Fstores%2Fmain.ts).  If you display `hiddenVaultSetup` in the template of your component does the value appear correct?  If it is just a problem with devtools, like maybe it ran into an error that silently killed its reactivity, opening in a new browser tab and/or restarting the app might help.